# Using Typesafe Console with Akka in a Servlet Application

Tags: scala, akka, atmosphere, typesafe

I have a servlet application using the Atmosphere Framework. Inside this servlet application I am also using Akka. Therefore it would be really useful if I could use the typesafe console to monitor the akka systsem.

The problem is that I start my application in debug mode using container:start, whereas atmosphere requires atmos:run as specified here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-atmos

Is it possible?

I have added these settings to my build.sbt which I borrowed from here http://resources.typesafe.com/console/docs/1.2.1/manual/sample-app.html#sample-application

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.atmos" % "trace-akka-2.2.0_2.10" % "1.2.1"

javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-javaagent:../lib/weaver/aspectjweaver.jar", "-Dorg.aspectj.tracing.factory=default", "-Djava.library.path=../lib/sigar")
```

In debug mode I use the xsbt-web plugin, so use the "container:start" command to start up the application.

Comment: Did you also change your application.conf file?